# Make fn the default function key behavior only for some of the function keys

Tags: keyboard, system-settings, macos

I find myself using the actual <kbd>F*</kbd> only for <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>, but for music and sound controls I use the function instead. I've tried using functions by default, and it works great for <kbd>F7</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>, but then I need to use <kbd>fn</kbd> for the first half. I've also tried disabling the functions by default, but then I end up using <kbd>fn</kbd> for the other half of the function keys.

Is there a way to configure the keyboard so they trigger the actual <kbd>F*</kbd> only for **some** function keys, and the function for others?